# Bit permutation tables in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Is there a pattern for, or a standard way to permute bits according to a *permutation table* that specifies for each bit position of the result - which position is taken from the source.

I.e. table `0322` would create result `0011` from `0010`

My current strategy has been to read each entry of the table - create a bitmask and then perform a binary AND of the mask and the source, OR`ing that with a cumulative result.

so to process the first table entry:

```
result |= ( ( (int) pow(2,table[0]) & source)
```

This just seems expensive and repetitive and homebrewed.  Am I missing some obvious standard easier way?

Comment: This is not a common operation, and when it is done it's usually a hardcoded set of operations rather than something table-driven. I doubt that you're going to find an off-the-shelf implementation. Possible easier way: Explode the value into bits via a shift-and-test loop, reassemble them as directed by your pattern by a shift-and-or loop.

Comment: There's a lot of fascinating reading on the subject [here](http://programming.sirrida.de/bit_perm.html#shuffle).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really expensive to use the `pow` function for this.  The repetitive and home-brewed parts are unavoidable.  A better way

```
result = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < table_size; i++ )
{ 
    result <<= 1;
    if ( source & (1 << table[i]) )
        result |= 1;
}
```

Comment: Check the generated code. A good optimising compiler would replace pow(2,xxx) by shift operations, making it quite cheap.

Answer (score 3):

One possible use for this kind of coding is implementing an encryption algorithm. I've used this in DES and S-boxes, although it was a while ago. The key point is that performance matters. You need something fast.

My recommendation is to precompute the masks and unroll the loop. For your 4 bit example:

```
int bits[4] = { 1, 2, 4, 8 };
result = (bits[table[0]] & source)
       | (bits[table[1]] & source)
       | (bits[table[2]] & source)
       | (bits[table[3]] & source);
```

[I don't think this is the right algorithm, but it matches the question.]

But I would check the generated code. A good enough optimising compiler could convert your code into exactly this!

Comment: If you have a fixed permutation table and you know exactly what it looks like you can create a custom masking (possibly optimised): either by hand or using tools like [this](http://programming.sirrida.de/calcperm.php).